# Is there a way to make integer values equal to local time on Raspberry Pi in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to make an amplifier produce sound when integer values equal the local time on a Raspberry Pi. I get the integers using google's firebase.

I have implemented a while loop to determine if the values are actually the same and when they reach the same number, the if statement I made doesn't go through.

This is the python code:

```
from firebase import firebase
from pygame import mixer
import time

def sound():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Twin-bell-alarm-clock-sound.mp3')

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://alarm-app-9c3ce.firebaseio.com/')


while True:
    result = int (firebase.get('/Time/Hour',None))
    result2 = int (firebase.get('/Time/Minute',None))
    print (result)
    print (result2)
    print (time.localtime().tm_hour)
    print (time.localtime().tm_min)
    sec=0

    if result == time.localtime().tm_hour and result2 == time.localtime().tm_min and sec==time.localtime().tm_sec:
        print('playing alarm')
        mixer.music.play()
        break
sound()
```

At least I expected to see "playing alarm" printed but nothing happens after the statement becomes true.

This is the output:

```
14   #Result for hour in firebase
50   #Result for minute in firebase
14   #Local hour in Raspberry Pi
49   #Local minute in Raspberry Pi
14
50
14
49
```

Once all corresponding values equal to one another, the program stops without the print statement and audio.

Comment: Could we see the output of this program? Also, why do you check for the condition of localtime().tm_sec == 0 ? It's pretty much useless as the loop will break at localtime().tm_sec anyways (as tm_min == result2 will become true at exactly the same time).